# Table width with multicolumn

Tags: tables, wrap, notes, multicolumn

I am producing lots of tables automatically with Stata (perhaps its useful to know that the top, content and bottom of the table are produced separately and then pasted together into one file I `\input`}. All of these tables have notes at the bottom which I insert using `\multicolumn`. In order to get the notes to wrap I need to define a fixed column width which I do in Table 2 below using `{p{\linewidth}}`. Does anybody have a suggestion how I can limit the width of the second table to the width of the first table?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

% Table 1 
\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering 
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi} 
\caption{bla \& table} 
\begin{tabular}{l*{3}{c}} \hline \addlinespace
1 & 2 & 3 \\  
4 & 5 & 6 \\  
7 & 8 & 9 \\  
\addlinespace \hline 
\end{tabular} 
\end{table}



% Table 2 
\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering 
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi} 
\caption{bla \& table} 
\begin{tabular}{l*{3}{c}} \hline \addlinespace   
1 & 2 & 3 \\ 
4 & 5 & 6 \\
 7 & 8 & 9 \\ 
\addlinespace \hline \addlinespace 
\multicolumn{3}{p{\linewidth}}{\footnotesize Standard errors in parentheses with
  \sym{*} indicating significance at 10\%, \sym{**} at 5\%, and \sym{***} at 1\%. 
  All reported standard error use the robust or sandwich estimator of variance.} 
\end{tabular} 
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: A tip: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863), they'll be marked as code, as can be seen in my edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: Do you mean `\multicolumn{3}{@{}p{\linewidth}@{}}{`

Comment: Thanks, Daniel. But how does \multicolumn{3}{@{}p{\linewidth}@{}} help me? Doesn't solve the table width problem.

Comment: The table markup is rather odd, why use `\sym` rather than a footnote macro and automatic numbering? the table preambles specify 4 columns but they only have 3 columns of data.  A package such as `threeparttable` automates measuring the width of the table and setting table notes to the same width.

Comment: Wasn't aware of {threeparttable}! Works like magic! Thanks!

Comment: @Max since David's comment allowed you to construct an answer for yourself, it would be helpful if you could post it as an answer. Self-answers are perfectly acceptable, and in this case very appropriate.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: `\sym` is what the [estout](http://repec.org/bocode/e/estout/) Stata package uses to indicate and format significance stars.
@Max: You might want to take a look at [Jörg Weber's blog posts](http://www.jwe.cc/2012/03/stata-latex-tables-estout/) on Stata tables in LaTeX and the [two](http://www.jwe.cc/2012/08/latex-and-stata-integration-solving-some-problems/) [follow-up](http://www.jwe.cc/2012/08/latex-stata-design/) posts. `threeparttable` is covered in the [second](http://www.jwe.cc/2012/08/latex-and-stata-integration-solving-some-problems/) post.

Answer (score 2):

The table markup is rather odd, why use `\sym` rather than a footnote macro and automatic numbering? the table preambles specify 4 columns but they only have 3 columns of data. A package such as `threeparttable` automates measuring the width of the table and setting table notes to the same width.